# JavaScript Guidance

Tags: javascript, html

I would like someone to help me with a problem I have. Currently my second part of my code is not working(i will mark it with two stars). I want it to change the second list to the length of the second list instead of the other way around. I would really appreciate the help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Uh-Oh the items are not in alphabetical order can you fix it!</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try To Fix It</button>
<p id="Items"></p>
<script>
    var Devices = ["Printer", "Router", "Tablet", "Speakers", "Bluetooth Mouse"]
    document.getElementById("Items").innerHTML = Devices;
    function myFunction() {
    Devices.sort();
    document.getElementById("Items").innerHTML = Devices;

        }
        </script>
<p>Oh-No I Cant read but i know numbers how much does that list contain </p>
<button onclick="dosfunction()">Find The Length</button>
<p id="Count"></p>
<script>
        var Devices2 = ["Printer", "Router", "Tablet", "Speakers", "BluetoothMouse"]
        document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = Devices2.length;
        function dosfunction () {
            Devices2.length;
            document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = Devices2;

        }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Just to be more clear.. when i run the script, i want it to display the list, then once the button is pressed, i want it to display the number of items in that list.  Currently it is doing it the other way round.

Comment: In my experience, "doesn't work" often means that the code is triggering a JavaScript error but the author is not aware of the JavaScript console that displays this information. Have you checked such console?

Comment: Have you tried `Devices2.length` instead of `Devices2` in the last line?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<p>Uh-Oh the items are not in alphabetical order can you fix it!</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try To Fix It</button>
<p id="Items"></p>
<script>

    var Devices = ["Printer", "Router", "Tablet", "Speakers", "Bluetooth Mouse"]
    document.getElementById("Items").innerHTML = Devices;
    function myFunction() {
    Devices.sort();
    document.getElementById("Items").innerHTML = Devices;

        }
        </script>
<p>Oh-No I Cant read but i know numbers how much does that list contain </p>
<button onclick="dosfunction()">Find The Length</button>
<p id="Count"></p>
<script>
    var Devices2 = ["Printer", "Router", "Tablet", "Speakers", "BluetoothMouse"]
    document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = Devices2;
    function dosfunction () {
        document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = Devices2.length;
    }
</script>
```

The part of interest is

```
var Devices2 = ["Printer", "Router", "Tablet", "Speakers", "BluetoothMouse"]
document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = Devices2;
function dosfunction () {
    document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = Devices2.length;
}
```

where I have swapped Devices2 and Devices2.length

Answer (score 0):

The only problem i found is with your  `dosfunction ()` .

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Uh-Oh the items are not in alphabetical order can you fix it!</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try To Fix It</button>
<p id="Items"></p>
<script>
   var Devices = ["Printer", "Router", "Tablet", "Speakers", "Bluetooth Mouse"]
   document.getElementById("Items").innerHTML = Devices;
   function myFunction() {
   Devices.sort();
   document.getElementById("Items").innerHTML = Devices;

    }
</script>
<p>Oh-No I Cant read but i know numbers how much does that list contain </p>
<button onclick="dosfunction()">Find The Length</button>
<p id="Count"></p>
<script>
    var Devices2 = ["Printer", "Router", "Tablet", "Speakers", "BluetoothMouse"]

    function dosfunction () {
       document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = Devices2.length;

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, you have to interchange those ..innerHTML codes -->
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D56U.jpg)

So, second part of your code must be this:

```
<script>
var Devices2 = ["Printer", "Router", "Tablet", "Speakers", "BluetoothMouse"]
        document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = Devices2;

        function dosfunction () {
            document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = Devices2.length;
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following steps :

```js
var Devices = ["Printer", "Router", "Tablet", "Speakers", "Bluetooth Mouse"];
document.getElementById("innerData").innerHTML = Devices;
function myFunction() {    
    document.getElementById("Items").innerHTML = Devices.length;
    document.getElementById("innerData").innerHTML = Devices;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create an array, then display its length.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="Items"></p>

<p id="innerData"></p>
```

Hope its helpful to you..